# How to get list of site-collections in a particular web application using Powershell in a text file

Tags: powershell

I want to extract list of site collection of one of the webapplication using powershell.

I found this url which does the same thing. But i want result in a text file.

http://sharepointhangout.com/powershell-how-to-extract-all-site-collections-in-webapplication/

How to get result in text file?

Comment: Have your searched on "Powershell write to text file"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the cmdlt [Out-File](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849882.aspx).

```
get-spsite -limit all -WebApplication http://yourWebapplicationUrl | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Users\YourUserName\Documents\spSites.txt"
```

Answer (score 4):

I have used below code to list all site collections from a Web Application into a `txt` file

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
Get-SPWebApplication http://yourwebapp.com | Get-SPSite | Select ID, Url | Out-File -FilePath "D:\spSites.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

The above solutions are fine. But you may encounter a problem with long site names. To make sure you get long string names use:

```
  get-spsite -limit all -WebApplication http://yourWebapplicationUrl | Ft -autosize -wrap | Out-File -FilePath "PathToYourFile"
```